# What is the value of (uintptr_t)(track + size)?

Tags: c

Assume track is a void pointer, size equals 8. Does it increase the address value by 8 bytes or 8 times the width of the uintptr_t type?

Comment: Adding to `void*` is not in the standard C.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! What if it is (uintptr_t)((char *)track + size)?

Comment: The cast has no effect on the math. The pointer arithmetic is done first, and the then cast is applied to the answer.

Comment: Then the address is increased for `size` elements of `char`. `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, so the address will be increased by 8.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you edit your post and show us an example of the arithmetic you're performing?  It's not clear from your question what you're asking.

Comment: An _address_ is not an _integer_.  Assuming an address is encoded like an integer is folly.  Increasing an address by `n`, even a `char *`, does certainly reflect an increase of `n` in `(uintptr_t)address`.

Comment: @AlgoEgoMango "What is the value of (uintptr_t)(track + size)?" --> even armed with an answer, what problem does this solve? _Why_ is it this info desired?  The upper level problem might make sense, but this one does not.